# App check unwanted enforcement on Firebase callable functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

Without having changed anything in my Firebase callable functions code, but having re-deployed them, now they suddenly start rejecting all function invocations from my app with the error shown below. I would like NOT to use App Check until I am ready to make the changes needed. How do I stop my callable (https.onCall) Firebase functions from rejecting invalid App Checks, and instead only reject invalid Authentication?

```
Failed to validate AppCheck token. FirebaseAppCheckError: Decoding App Check token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents the Firebase App Check token.
    at FirebaseAppCheckError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAppCheckError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAppCheckError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app-check/app-check-api-client-internal.js:187:28)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app-check/token-verifier.js:82:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'app-check/invalid-argument',
    message: 'Decoding App Check token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents the Firebase App Check token.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app-check'
} 

Callable request verification failed: AppCheck token was rejected. {"verifications":{"app":"INVALID","auth":"VALID"}}
```

The code rejecting all requests due to invalid App Check is super simple:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
exports.example = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return "test";
}
```

Package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12"
},
"main": "index.js",
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^9.10.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
},
```

Comment: This looks like a bug:  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/967

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience. The docs say that you are supposed to check like this[1]:

```
  if (context.app == undefined) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called from an App Check verified app.')
  }
```

But, this is not the case in my experience, the App Check starts to be enforced immediately the moment you add App Check to your app.

### EDIT:

moreover, even without doing any check in my code, I can see this in the logs whenever I call one of my functions:

```
Callable request verification passed {"verifications":{"auth":"VALID","app":"VALID"}}
```

So it seems App Check happens automatically, at least in Callable Functions. If you want to bypass AppCheck in one of your functions, you might want to try an HTTP function instead (not Callable).

[1] Source https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions

Comment: Yes this was also exactly what I noticed, and thought I could make use of that exact functionality. Contrary to the documentation, it seems all the checks in reality are done automatically before the cloud function is even executed

Comment: @thamey see my edit I found out a bit more info by checking the function logs.

Answer (score 1):

From protocol specification for [https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference):

> Optional [Header]: X-Firebase-AppCheck: The Firebase App Check token provided by the client app making the request. The backend automatically verifies this token and decodes it, injecting the appId in the handler's context. If the token cannot be verified, the request is rejected. (Available for SDK >=3.14.0)

My guess is that calls to your callable function contains an invalid App Check token.

If you haven't configured DeviceCheck or/and App Attest attestation providers on your project but have included the App Check library on your client, your client code may be including a dummy App Check token when calling your function (full details on this [github issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6794#issuecomment-897129319)).

Firebase team is working through changes to make the experience less confusing. Please follow along in http://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/967 and https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6794 for status.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the same when I run the app on an emulator, after running on a real device is running without any problems. That's what happens to me.